# Android: Remove Value from SQLite Database Row

Tags: android, sqlite

Good Day,

I have an application that is using a database to store integers in a column programatically.  Part of the undo process needed in the app would require that entry to then be removed, because another query checks for a null return from this column.

Here is my method for writing the int to the column:

```
    public int updateItem(String database, String table, int row, String column, int value) {
        ....

        SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase
                (DB_PATH + database, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);           
        ContentValues entries = new ContentValues();
        entries.put(column, value);       
        return db.update(table, entries, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(row) });
    }
```

Can someone pleas advise on how to then remove the entry from this row/column, allowing it to again return a null response?

Thank you,
Josh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
entries.putNull(column);
```

instead of

```
entries.put(column, value).
```